# Listview getting disappeared

Tags: android, listview

I am facing one problem with Listview

Description : there are two buttons on the header of the screen, on clicking any of which calls a webservice, gets a response saves that response into an arraylist and I display the data which is there in the arraylist in the listview. First time whenever a button is clicked data is displayed into the listview but whenever the button is clicked second time previous listview get disappeared on pre-execute of Asynctask and is populated again when the webservice call is done, but my problem is I dont want my listview to get disappeared until the web service call is finished.

Answer (score 0):

assign the new array list data to list view in post execute , don't disturb the list view array meanwhile..

Comment: That I had already done but the thing is suppose if the internet connectivity gets lost somewhere between the call then I want to display the previous data which is there my arraylist

Comment: then just store data in temp array list in pre execute and put a check if no internet on post execute load the temp list..

Comment: see what I tried is I have not cleared the loaded arraylist before the successful execution of the second webservice call, and set the adapter in the pre-execute method, even it didnt worked out

Answer (score 0):

Better to put pre-execute's code inside  post-execute method.